# spmetal generates code for all sharepoint lists except one

Tags: spmetal

I used SPMetal to generate code for the lists on my SharePoint site as per [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798329.aspx). I have several custom lists on the site. SPMetal generates code for all of the lists except one. There is nothing different about the list that SPMetal is ignoring. Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: I've tried re-creating the list and have re-run SPMetal a few times. The list name is "Population Types", in case that makes a difference.